# window.innerWidth much less than screen resolution in mobile browsers

Tags: html, mobile-browser

I am using window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, window.outerWidth and window.outerHeight to layout the components in my mobile webpage. However I noticed an interesting fact: The values returned on mobile browsers are much smaller than the actual screen resolution. For example:

My PC: innerWidth: 1920, outerHeight: 1056. res: 1920 * 1080

My galaxy s3: innerWidth: 360, outerHeight: 567. res: (not sure but must be larger than this)

ipad air: innerWidth:768, innerHeight: 928. res: 2048 * 1536

The kik messenger browser run on ipad air: innerWidth: 320, outerHeight: 480. res: 2048 * 1536

I am not sure why this happened. I am using canvases to draw images in my webpage. The images are crystal clear on PC browsers. However a little blurred on mobile browsers. If run in the browser of kik messenger, the text and images are super blurry. I think the blurry text and images maybe caused by the issue so it should helpful to figure this out.

Comment: `window.devicePixelRatio` is your friend here.

Comment: Found helpful articles with this keyword. Thank you. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/